# GraalVM HelloWorld Application NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have a code and i want to run on GraalVM

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Above code is my basic code.

```
native-image 21.0.1 2023-10-17
GraalVM Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
Substrate VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12, serial gc, compressed references)
```

above code is my graalvm version.

When i run below commands

> javac HelloWorld.java 
> native-image HelloWorld,

I have an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: org/fsk/HelloWorld)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.defineClass(NativeImageClassLoader.java:500)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.findClassViaClassPath(NativeImageClassLoader.java:452)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.loadClass(NativeImageClassLoader.java:640)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageClassLoader.forName(ImageClassLoader.java:307)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageClassLoader.forName(ImageClassLoader.java:303)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ImageClassLoader.forName(ImageClassLoader.java:312)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:434)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:720)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:142)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:97)
```

My ide is Intellij IDE 2023.3

And i am using MacBook with using Turkish Language

How can i fix this.?

Comment: do you have a `package` declaration on the 1st line of the hello world file?

Comment: Yes, it has a package name.

```
package org.fsk;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to run the `native-image` compilation from the root directory, i.e. the directory that contains directory `org`. We would then reference the class to compile by its fully, qualified name: `native-image org.fsk.HelloWorld`. Same holds true btw if we try to run the compiled file (`java org.fsk.HelloWorld`), so this is not really related to `native-image`.

Comment: @Turing85 so thanks ((: It was run.